# comparing values that you get from database in java and sql

Tags: java, sql

im trying to compare the two values i get from my database and will return true if BOTH values are null or it doesnt exist in my database. And i already try debugging in netbeans it will jump from rs.getString("post_id").equals(""); to return liked; it will not read the next rs.getString and if statement. here is my code by the way

```
public boolean likedPost()
{
    String thePostID = POSTID();
    String likerName = objInfo.name;
    boolean liked = true;

    try
    {
        String sql = "select * from Like where post_id=? and people_who_like=?";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,thePostID);
        pst.setString(2,likerName);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        boolean comparePostID = rs.getString("post_id").equals("");
        boolean compareLiker = rs.getString("people_who_like").equals("");

        if(liked == (comparePostID && compareLiker))
            liked = true;
        else
            liked = false;
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }

    return liked;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare String using **StringUtils** class **(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils)**. `isEmpty()` method of StringUtils class internally checks that given String is null or is Empty or not.

```
String postId = rs.getString("post_id")
String liker =  rs.getString("people_who_like");

if(StringUtils.isEmpty(postId) && StringUtils.isEmpty(postId)) {
    liked = true;
} else {
    liked = false;
}
```

**EDIT** : You can make things simple like below

```
if (postId!= null && liker!= null && !postId.equals("") && !liker.equals("")) {

            liked = true;

        } else {

            liked = false;
        }
```

Comment: hello thank you for replying, by the way the isEmpty shows an error that says can't find symbol.

Comment: you should include apache commons lang jar in your classpath. Download jar from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: sorry sir i tried to download it and add the jar zip file to my library but still same error. can you instruct me sorry im new in java

Comment: @CyranLemoncito - no issues, you can make things simple i have edited my solution

Comment: @CyranLemoncito - great.. enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
String comparePostID = rs.getString("post_id");
String compareLiker = rs.getString("people_who_like");

if(comparePostID && comparePostID && !comparePostID.equals("") && !compareLiker.equals(""))
    liked = true;
else
    liked = false;
```